# Javascript slice isn't giving me correct array length values

Tags: javascript

[image]

Why does it say length 1 instead of 4? 
The following is what I'm trying to push and slice. I try and append items.image_urls and slice them into 5 each.

`items.image_urls` is my dictionary array.

```
var final_push = []
final_push.push(items.image_urls.splice(0,5))
console.log(final_push.length)## gives me 1...?

var index = 0
final_push.forEach(function(results){
   index++ ##this gives me one. I would need 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5. Somehting along that.
}
```

items.image_urls looks like this:
It's an iteration of arrays with image urls.
[image]

Comment: Because it's an array of arrays. You have to look in
`final_push[0]`

Comment: you probably want to replace final_push.push(items.image_urls.splice(0,5)) with final_push =items.image_urls.splice(0,5)

Comment: You're using splice instead of slice.

Comment: Maybe you need `final_push[0].forEach(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `items.image_urls.splice(0,5)` returns an array of items removed from `items.image_urls`. When you call `final_push.push(items.image_urls.splice(0,5));`, this whole array is pushed as one item to the `final_push` array, so it now looks like `[["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", "url5"]]` (2-dimensional array). You can access this whole array by calling `final_push[some_index]`.

But what you want instead is to add every element of `items.image_urls.splice(0,5)` to the `final_push`. You can use a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to achieve this:

```
final_push.push(...items.image_urls.splice(0,5));
```

> Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string
>   to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function
>   calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected

This is exactly our case, because [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) expects one or more arguments:

```
arr.push(element1[, ...[, elementN]])
```

And here is an example:

```js
let items = {
    image_urls: ["url1", "url2", "url3", "url4", "url5", "url6", "url7", "url8", "url9", "url10"]
};

let final_push = [];
final_push.push(...items.image_urls.splice(0,5)); 

console.log(final_push.length);
console.log(JSON.stringify(final_push));
console.log(JSON.stringify(items.image_urls));
```

**Note:** do not confuse [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - the first one *returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object* while the second *changes the contents of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements* and *returns an array containing the deleted elements*.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, In my case using your example so you understand my scenario better;
I have dictionary items with multiple image_urls array. Each containing different length; When I do what you said; it returned me each image_urls array first five items only. But 5x items of the entire list.

Comment: @Dilli So what exactly are you trying to achieve? It would be nice if you attached your `items` structure example.

Comment: Would you mind if I open up a chat; where I can paste my codes; that'd be much easier ;)

Comment: @Dilli go ahead

Comment: While I figure out how to do that; I've added an image of what items.image_urls is giving me.

Comment: @Dilli so items.image_urls is an array of arrays? And you want to copy all these urls to the result array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164146/discussion-between-dilli-and-kirill-simonov).

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be a nested array. So if you would access index 0, and then work on that array like below it will probably work:

```
console.log(final_push[0].length); //should print 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The author is mixing up `splice` and `slice`. Probably a typo :)

You start at the beginning (0) and then delete 5 items.

Comment: `slice` and `splice` both return the same thing, the difference is whether they modify the original array.